# java nio: incomplete file transfer

Tags: java, file, nio, transfer, channel

I'm trying to transmit large video files from clients to a server using java NIO. I seem to require using NIO because the files I want to send are much larger than the apparent file size limit with regular IO, which is about 2GB...my video files have been as large as 50GB each. Right now, i'm just trying to build a small program to understand the concepts. it will later be added to a larger program.

My problem lies in the fact that only the first few hundred kilobytes of the file get saved on the server. Each time I run it, a different about of data gets saved on the server. Can anyone help me with a solution? (and any other suggestions you might have...NIO is new to me) THANKS!

### Here's how it works:

The client will have a collection of files to send to the server. The client will establish a connection with the server, and the server will reply saying it's ready. The client sends the file header information. The server then says its ready to receive the file contents. The client then sends the contents of the file. When the file is fully transmitted, it repeats over with the next file until no more files need to be sent.

## Main Client

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    FileSender fileSender = new FileSender("localhost", 7146);
    fileSender.addFileToSend(new File("C:\\url\\to\\file1.jpg"));
    fileSender.addFileToSend(new File("C:\\url\\to\\file2.jpg"));
    fileSender.addFileToSend(new File("C:\\url\\to\\file3.jpg"));
    fileSender.sendFiles();
}
```

## FileSender

```
private static String serverAddress;
private static int port;
private static Charset charSet = Charset.forName(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));

private SocketChannel server = null;
private File file;
private RandomAccessFile aFile;
private FileChannel fileChannel;
private long filesize, transmittedSoFar;
private int current;
private ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(131072); //128k
private ByteBuffer responseBuffer;
private CharBuffer charBuffer;
private CharsetDecoder charDecoder = charSet.newDecoder();
private Selector selector;
private ArrayList<File> filesToSend = new ArrayList<>(0);
private int fileCountTracker = 0;

FileSender(String serverAddress, int port) {
    FileSender.serverAddress = serverAddress;
    FileSender.port = port;
}

public void sendFiles() {
    try {
        server = SocketChannel.open();
        server.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddress, port));
        server.configureBlocking(false);
        System.out.println("Connected to Server");
        selector = Selector.open();
        server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        waitForResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void waitForResponse() throws Exception {
    //TODO: track time. abort loop after 10 sec? 30 sec?
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("waiting for a response from server");
        selector.select();
        Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
            if (key.isReadable()) {
                responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
                server.read(responseBuffer);
                responseBuffer.flip();

                try {
                    charBuffer = charDecoder.decode(responseBuffer);
                    responseBuffer.clear();
                    String response = charBuffer.toString();
                    System.out.println(response);
                    if (response.startsWith("[readyForHeader]")) {
                        System.out.println("Received response: ready for header");
                        sendHeader();
                    }
                    else if (response.startsWith("[readyForBody]")) {
                        System.out.println("Received response: ready for body");
                        sendData();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("unknown response");
                        System.out.println(response);
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("error decoding file info");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void addFileToSend(File file) {
    filesToSend.add(file);
}

void sendHeader() {
    System.out.println("Tracker: "+fileCountTracker);
    try {
        if (filesToSend.size() > fileCountTracker) { //still more files to send
            System.out.println("a file exists at this array index");
            this.file = filesToSend.get(fileCountTracker);
            filesize = file.length();
            aFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
            transmittedSoFar = 0;

            //generate file info buffers to send to server
            byte[] fileInfoBytes = getFileMeta(file);
            ByteBuffer lengthBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4); //length of file info
            lengthBuffer.putInt(0, fileInfoBytes.length);
            System.out.println("Source info length: "+fileInfoBytes.length);
            ByteBuffer infoBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(fileInfoBytes); //file info data

            //send file info buffers
            sendByteBuffer(lengthBuffer);
            sendByteBuffer(infoBuffer);
        } else {
            System.out.println("sending zero to indicate no more files");
            ByteBuffer lengthBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4); //length of file info
            lengthBuffer.putInt(0, 0); //tell server sending zero bytes. server will end connection
            sendByteBuffer(lengthBuffer);
            terminate();
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        terminate();
    }
}

void sendData() {
    try {
        fileChannel = aFile.getChannel();

        while ((current = fileChannel.read(buffer)) > 0 || buffer.position() > 0) {
            transmittedSoFar = transmittedSoFar + (long)current;
            System.out.println(Math.round(transmittedSoFar*100/filesize)+" "+transmittedSoFar);
            buffer.flip();
            server.write(buffer);
            buffer.compact();
        }
        System.out.println("End of file reached..");
        aFile.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION");
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO EXCEPTION");
        e.getMessage();
    }
    fileCountTracker++;
}

byte[] getFileMeta(File file) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer fileInfo = new StringBuffer();

    BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);

    fileInfo.append(file.getName() + "\n");
    fileInfo.append(file.length() + "\n");
    fileInfo.append(attr.creationTime() + "\n");

    byte[] infoBytes = fileInfo.toString().getBytes();

    return infoBytes;
}

void sendByteBuffer(ByteBuffer bb) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("sending: "+bb.toString());
    server.write(bb);
    bb.rewind();
}

void terminate() {
    try {
        server.close();
        System.out.println("Connection closed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## MainServer

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    FileReceiver fileReceiver = new FileReceiver(7146);
    fileReceiver.initReceive();
}
```

## FileReceiver

```
static Charset charSet = Charset.forName(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\n]");//new line
static int port;
static BytesTypeToReceive bytesType;

ServerSocketChannel server;
SocketChannel client;

ByteBuffer byteBuffer, responseBuffer;
CharBuffer charBuffer;
CharsetDecoder charDecoder = charSet.newDecoder();
RandomAccessFile aFile = null;
String fileInfo[];
int headerLength;
long remaining;
Selector selector;

public FileReceiver(int port) {
    FileReceiver.port = port;
}

public void initReceive() {
    try {
        server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        server.configureBlocking(false);
        server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        selector = Selector.open();
        server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        waitForResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        close();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void waitForResponse() throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for data from client");
        int selCount = selector.select();
        System.out.println("selector count: "+selCount);
        Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
            if (key.isReadable()) {
                if (bytesType == BytesTypeToReceive.HEADER) {
                    receiveHeader();
                } else {
                    receiveBody();
                }
            } else if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection established...." + client.getRemoteAddress());
                client.configureBlocking(false);
                bytesType = BytesTypeToReceive.HEADER;
                client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                sendResponse("[readyForHeader]");
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }
}

private void receiveHeader() {
    System.out.println("Receiving header data");
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);

    try {
        //read length
        while (byteBuffer.remaining() > 0) client.read(byteBuffer);
        System.out.println("what is this? "+byteBuffer.toString());
        byteBuffer.rewind();
        System.out.println("and this? "+byteBuffer.toString());
        System.out.println("Info length is " + byteBuffer.getInt(0));

        if (byteBuffer.getInt(0) == 0) {
            System.out.println("no more files. end connection");
            throw new IOException();
        }

        //resize to size indicated in first buffer
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteBuffer.getInt(0));

        //read file info
        while (byteBuffer.remaining() > 0) client.read(byteBuffer);
        byteBuffer.flip();

        //decode file info
        try {
            charBuffer = charDecoder.decode(byteBuffer);
            byteBuffer.clear();
             System.out.println(charBuffer.toString());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error decoding file info");
            return;
        }
        fileInfo = pattern.split(charBuffer);

        System.out.println("info0: "+fileInfo[0]);
        System.out.println("info1: "+fileInfo[1]);

        remaining = Long.parseLong(fileInfo[1]);

        bytesType = BytesTypeToReceive.BODY;
        //tell client ready for file data
        sendResponse("[readyForBody]");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception for checkForData. No more data?");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Reads the bytes from socket and writes to file
 *
 * @param socketChannel
 */
//private void readFileFromSocket(SocketChannel socketChannel, int infoLength) {
private void receiveBody() throws Exception {
    int current;
    System.out.println("About to receive "+remaining+" bytes.");
    try {
        //read file data
        aFile = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\folder\\to\\save\\to\\"+fileInfo[0], "rw");
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(131072);
        FileChannel fileChannel = aFile.getChannel();
        while (((current = client.read(byteBuffer)) > 0 || byteBuffer.position() > 0) && remaining > 0) {
            remaining = remaining - (long)current;
            System.out.println(current+" "+remaining);  
            byteBuffer.flip();
            fileChannel.write(byteBuffer);
            byteBuffer.compact();
        }
        fileChannel.close();
        aFile.close();      
        System.out.println(current +" - End of file");
        bytesType = BytesTypeToReceive.HEADER;
        sendResponse("[readyForHeader]");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION");
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO EXCEPTION");
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("INTERRUPTED EXCEPTION");
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
void sendResponse(String response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Sending response: "+response);
    byte[] data = response.getBytes("UTF-8");
    responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    client.write(responseBuffer);
    responseBuffer.rewind();

}
public void close() {
    try {
        client.close();
        server.close();
        System.out.println("connection closed");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can copy files larger then 2g with the standard IO classes, but you need to do in chunks, rather then trying to read/write the entire buffer into a single "large" array, this is how it was done before NIO

Comment: @MadProgrammer This was never how it was done in my circle :-)

Comment: @EJP What? You never used `InputStream`/`OutputStream` and read/write it to a `byte[]`?  Lucky you, you must have missed Java 1.3 then

Comment: @MadProgrammer It isn't clear what exactly you're talking about. I've never used `InputStream` to read an entire file into memory. I don't see what Java 1.3 has to do with it. The `InputStream` API hasn't changed since 1.1.2 at least, and there is nothing in it that reads entire files into memory without a loop.

Comment: @EJP I wasn't talking about reading the entire file into memory (that's kind of crazy :P), I was talking about using a small `byte[]` (array) buffer to read/write smaller chunks, and the NIO API was introduced in 1.4, so prior to that, it was one of ways to read/write files.  Using this method you can read/write files of any size, that was my point.  But, if the OP wants to use the NIO API, I have no issue with that, just wanted to correct the point about the "other apis" been limited to 2gb

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well it's still as clear as mud. *All* the APis are limited to 2Gb *at a time,* as that's the maximum size of a `byte[]` array. You have to *loop,* whether `java.io,`, NIO, asynchronous I/O, whatever. The only exception is the `transferTo/From()` APIs, where you still have to loop but the unit of transfer is a long, not an int, or, similarly, the scatter/gather NIO methods. And the OP *is* looping, and is *not* using file-sized arrays. Really the point escapes me.

Comment: @ejp Make a `byte[]`, maybe 4k `byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];`, use `InputStream#read(byte[])`, `int bytesRead = is.read(buffer)`, write said buffer through `OutputStream(byte[], int, int)`, repeat till `bytesRead` is `-1` ... or in this case, you reach known file size :P - which you've  pointed out was been sent wrong :P

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of chunking the file. I've also heard, however, that the nio channels are faster than the steams since steams go byte-by-byte, where a channel sends in chunks. if there is a notable performance loss with not using nio, then i'd really prefer not to use it...especially since we're talking about huge video files.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The code you posted corresponds exactly to the description in my immediately previous comment. I still have no idea what point you're trying to make here. We seem to be in a state of furious agreement that you should always copy files in chunks.

Comment: @EJP Cool, I'll live with that :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the problem:

```
while (((current = client.read(byteBuffer)) > 0
```

As your socket is configured non blocking and you don't have any selects on the input it'll quickly consume incoming data and stop as read will return -1 or 0.

Actually client hs similar problem but it'll just burn CPU while trying to push data to overloaded socket.

Comment: i replaced the while condition to be simply "while (remaining > 0) and placed the client.read inside the loop. i'll have to play with the read/write selection keys so it doesn't "burn cpu", but at least the files copied in their entirety. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

The only file size limitation here is in your own code. You're sending the file size as an int, in 4 bytes.

Use a long.

NB you don't need to allocate huge buffers. You don't even need to send the file size, except for checking. You can use buffer sizes of the order of 32-64k. You copy code is good.

Comment: The 4-byte buffer holds the length of the header information, not the filesize itself. the filesize is mixed in with other information, like the filename...and in the future I will probably add more meta data.I've tried smaller buffers in the past instead of 128k, but then the resulting file is even smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

server.configureBlocking(false);

server should in blocking mode, because you should't write data into buffer when socket is still reading data form buffer.